# proper sources for a Kehilla's obligations

Tags: tzibur-community

I was recently asked what kind of obligations a Kehilla has to its members, meaning which functions does it have to offer. Also, the 2nd part of the question is if there is a ranking list, ie which have to come first.
I know that a Mikve comes first (even over a Sefer Torah). But what of the rest?
Are there any sources for other things like youth groups, or even thing like chess clubs? Could there be problems to pay for these kind of activities from the membership money, which in most cases is maaser money?